# ng-model not updating on datetime field changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have a problem with a datepicker directive on AngularJS. The input has assigned the directive as well as an ng-model, but it doesn't update the model when someone picks a date. But, if after a date gets picked, you manually modify the date directly on the input field, it gets updated.

This is my directive:

```
.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                element.datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        scope.date = date;
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And this is my HTML input:

```
<input type="datetime" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedUser.birthday" jqdatepicker />
```

**Note**: That field is on a modal called from a controller like so:

```
$modalInstance = $modal.open({
    scope: $scope,
    templateUrl: 'views/modal_user_form.html',
    windowClass: "animated flipInY"
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with just using `onClose` event instead of `onSelect`, but I noticed small mistake in your code - you should use `ngModelCtrl`:

```
.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.$apply(function() { 
                      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kU5g5ov1tduycjd8tUWN?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, worked as a charm. So that onSelect method never fires?

Comment: @Multitut hm... I noticed that you modified scope directly instead of using `ngModel` controller... Changed code to be more correct and `onSelect` start working as expected. Now I don't understand why it worked with `onClose` :)